# search Extended asci character in unix

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, sh

I want to search a string which contains extended ascii character like © or » or ¼ or ½. I am tring search above pattern with grep command like this
grep -E  '^[a-fA-F0-9\251]+$' file

Above code is not working.

Comment: it will be difficult to do that.. try the hex values

Answer (score 0):

Use hexadecimal values for the corresponding extended characters.

```
0xbc for ¼
0xbd for ½
0xa9 for ©
```

Try Perl for such cases. Here is an example for ¼

```
$ echo -e "abc\xbcdef" > extended_ascii.txt

$ cat extended_ascii.txt
abc▒def

$ cat -tv extended_ascii.txt
abcM-<def
```

Note below grep doesn't match it

```
$ grep "\xbc" extended_ascii.txt
```

Perl matches

```
$ perl -ne ' print if /\xbc/ ' extended_ascii.txt
abc▒def

$
```

If you want to match any extended char, outside of the ascii range, then use the below

```
$ perl -ne ' print if /[^\x20-\x7f]/ ' extended_ascii.txt
abc▒def

$
```

Note: My terminal displays ▒ for \xbc, it could be different for yours.